# Choosing Action Outlet by default when control-drag object from interface builder to swift file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

It's a well known feature in XCode that we can hold control an object from interface builder to swift file to make a connection..

[image]

Is there any shortcut to make the connecttion by default an `action` instead of `outlet` ...? this is useful when dragging `UIButton`s.

Comment: An alternative is to do the *opposite* sequence for creating an `IBOutlet`. (1) Create your `IBAction`, remembering to set the `sender`. (2) Create you `UIButton` in IB. (3) Control drag *from* the IBAction *to* the button. Backwards, but it's still the same amount of steps (and you still have the assistant editor to help you).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding custom shortcuts, As far as i heard. Probably No.

Many developers have had this problem. fortunately Xcode 10 is here to help! Now, if you command-drag above the first function, it'll default as an outlet. Below the first function, the default is an action. Brilliant!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @DeyaEldeen I think if there were one apple wouldn’t have had this feature implemented. Right now I’m upgrading to MacOS Mojave and I’d be happy to keep you updated